# How to open the image gallery with angularjs ionic cordova camera?

Tags: angularjs, file, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile app for `android`. For this I use the JBoss Developer Studio, because I need access to the file system for the application. I also need the `org.apache.cordova.file` Plugin. Now if I want to test the application with CordovaSim, then I get the following log output:

```
!JavaScript ERROR: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?' on line 2 for http://localhost:59800/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileWriter.js 
!JavaScript ERROR: Error: Module cordova-plugin-file.FileWriter does not exist. on line 1371 for http://localhost:59800/ripple/cordova/cordova-3.5.0.js 
!JavaScript ERROR: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.camera.getPicture')
http://localhost:59800/js/services.js:9 

(SWT:6181): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1285 was not found when attempting to remove it
!JavaScript ERROR: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.camera.getPicture')
http://localhost:59800/js/services.js:9 

(SWT:6181): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1457 was not found when attempting to remove it
!JavaScript LOG: deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. 
!JavaScript LOG: Channel not fired: onPluginsReady 
!JavaScript LOG: Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
```

What can I do?

my service.js:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Camera', ['$q', function($q) {

  return {
    getPicture: function(options) {
      var q = $q.defer();

      navigator.camera.getPicture(function(result) {
        // Do any magic you need
        q.resolve(result);
      }, function(err) {
        q.reject(err);
      }, options);

      return q.promise;
    }
  }
}])
```

my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
     <script src="js/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ngStorage.min.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">Photos</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content padding="true">
      <button ng-click="getPhoto()" class="button button-block button-primary">Take Photo</button>
      <img ng-src="{{lastPhoto}}" style="max-width: 100%">
    </ion-content>
  </body>
</html>
```

my app.js:

```
var facebookExample = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngStorage', 'ngCordova','starter.services'])

    facebookExample.config(function($compileProvider){
          $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
        })

        facebookExample.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
          $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            if(window.StatusBar) {
              // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
              StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
          });
        })

        facebookExample.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Camera) {

          $scope.getPhoto = function() {
            Camera.getPicture().then(function(imageURI) {
              console.log(imageURI);
              $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
            }, function(err) {
              console.err(err);
            }, {
              quality: 75,
              targetWidth: 320,
              targetHeight: 320,
              saveToPhotoAlbum: false
            });
          };

        })
```

Comment: Can you post your source code? `services.js` and your `index.html` for example?

Comment: Look to my question please, I edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the `cordova.js` script on top of the cordova related scripts:

```
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
```

Why are you writing your own `Camera factory` when the same is already shipped by [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/)? You are already using it, so you could try this:

```
facebookExample.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

  // Put your cordova related code after the deviceready event
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    var options = {
      quality: 75,
      targetWidth: 320,
      targetHeight: 320,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
      console.log(imageData);
      $scope.lastPhoto = imageData;
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

  }, false);

});
```

Comment: i solved of this error ('undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.camera.getPicture')
but now is dispaly this error (!JavaScript ERROR: Error: Module cordova-plugin-file.FileWriter does not exist.)

Comment: How did you install the plugin? You should have done it like: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`

Comment: Look in your `plugins` folder, is there any `cordova-plugin-file` or `org.apache.cordova.file` folder?

Comment: i use this command to install plugin of file: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file

Comment: in my plugins forlder ,i have a cordova-plugin-file

Comment: Have look [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/apache-cordova-file-plugin-does-not-load/18006). Obviously `CordovaSIM` is related with your error. Try to use Android Simulator instead!

Comment: I solved but an other error is display (!JavaScript ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $cordovaCamera on line 394 for http://localhost:42715/js/app.js )

Comment: Be sure to inject the $cordovaCamera service into your controller, like i did on the first line above `facebookExample.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera)` It would be better so see your code relating to `line 394` above and below

Comment: I solved but an other error (!JavaScript ERROR: Can't find variable: imageURI) what can i do ??

Comment: My mistake in my example code. I edited it above by replacing `imageURI` by `ìmageData`

Comment: thanks a lot ,thank you very much ,i'm beginner in development cordova angularjs

Comment: hi @Beat please how to convert this image to format json